# How to toggle audio play() pause() with a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have added an audio to my website, which is playing when site is opened. Now I want add play/pause button to toggle the audio.

This is how I tried it:

```
<audio id="myAudio" autoplay >
 <source src="mp3/background-music.mp4" type='audio/mp4'>
 Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>

<a type="button" class="play-pause" title="play/pause"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></a>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var playing = false;

    $('a.audio-btn').click(function() {
        if (playing == false) {
            document.getElementById('myAudio').play();
            playing = true;
            $(this).text("stop sound");

        } else {
            document.getElementById('myAudio').pause();
            playing = false;
            $(this).text("restart sound");
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

But its not working for me. Can anybody tell me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For demo purpose, i add `video` tag, to work with audio you can replace `video` to `audio` tag and Use

```
$('.play-pause')
```

Instead of

```
$('a.audio-btn')
```

For audio use this at the place of `video` tag :

```
<audio id="myAudio" autoplay>
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type='audio/mp4'>
   Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var playing = true;
 $('.play-pause').click(function () {
  if (playing == false) {
   document.getElementById('myAudio').play();
   playing = true;
   $(this).text("Sop Sound");

  } else {
   document.getElementById('myAudio').pause();
   playing = false;
   $(this).text("Restart Sound");
  }
 });
});
```

```css
a {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}
video {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="myAudio" autoplay>
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
 Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</video>
<a type="button" class="play-pause" title="play/pause">Play / Pause</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `$('a.audio-btn')` into `$('a.play-pause')`.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is not working? Does the button not appear, does it not function?

I would suggest using something like the following:

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    myAudio.pause()
  } else {
    myAudio.play();
  }
};
myAudio.onplaying = function() {
  isPlaying = true;
};
myAudio.onpause = function() {
  isPlaying = false;
};
```